# .htaccess redirect URL and remove .php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

My current .htaccess file is like this It hides .php from the url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now I want to redirect my site to also remove www  i.e I want to redirect
    http://www.thefutureshop.com.pk/index.php
    
to
    
    http://thefutureshop.com.pk

My site is built using codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Replace:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
to
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

For more Read this http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-remove-index-php-file-from-codeigniter-url/